# Add anychart to Apex 5 using Java Script

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex-5, anychart

I want to have a 100% customizable chart on my Apex application. For this purpose I want to add an Anychart with Java Script and use custom xml.

I added the OracleAnyChart.swf and Preloader.swf files to Shared Components -> Static Application Files.

I have this code under "Execute when Page Loads"

```
AnyChart.renderingType = anychart.RenderingType.SVG_PREFERRED;   
var chart = new AnyChart('#APP_IMAGES#OracleAnyChart.swf','#APP_IMAGES#Preloader.swf', 'be_chart');
chart.width = 600;
chart.height = 150; 
chart.messages = {
loadingConfig: "Loading config...",
waitingForData: "Waiting for data..."}
console.log('ID = ' || chart.id);

var jqxhr =  apex.server.process( 'GET_BEXML',
                                { 
                                    pageItems: "#BE_DATA"
                                },
                                {
                                    dataType : 'text'
                                }
                                );  
jqxhr.done(function(pData) {
                       console.log(chart.id);
                       chart.setData($v('BE_DATA'));
                       chart.write('container_be');  
                       //chart.refresh(); 
    }         
    );
```

My On demand process "GET_BEXML" sets the item BE_DATA with correct XML, but the chart does not render.

[image: Chart not rendering properly]

I tried to call

```
var chart = getChartById('be_chart');
chart.setData($v('BE_DATA'));
chart.refresh();
```

from a Dynamic action but it appears that I cant call any anychart functions in the Dynamic actions' scope, it says "getCharById its not defined".

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a method that doesn't exist.
You need to reference the AnyChart object like this (and maybe change the variable name so you don't overwrite your original chart object):

```
var mychart = AnyChart.getChartById('be_chart');
```

*Actually...

I responded to the reason for you failed getChartById call.

I've realized that wasn't the actual question.*
Have you tried passing the data directly in to the done() callback function?
This method works. And what is REALLY great about it, is there is **NO 32K LIMIT** on the data you can return.

```
-- Apex Application Process "GET_BEXML"
declare
    v_limit constant pls_integer := 32767;
    v_buff  varchar2(32767);
    v_data  clob;
    v_os    pls_integer := 1;
    v_len   pls_integer := 0;
begin
    v_data := get_anydata_xml_doc;  -- a PL/SQL function returning your AnyData xml
    v_len  := dbms_lob.getlength(v_data);
    while v_os < v_len
    loop
        dbms_lob.read(v_data, v_limit, v_os, v_buff);
        htp.prn(v_buff);
        v_os := v_os + v_limit;
    end loop;
end;
```

---

```
// "Execute when Page Loads"
    var jqxhr = apex.server.process('GET_BEXML', {}, {dataType:'text'});
    jqxhr.done(function(pData) {
        console.log(pData.substring(1,50));
        chart.setData(pData);
        chart.write('container_be');
    });
```

Of course you could create you AnyData xml clob on the fly within Apex as well.